# родитель по высоте дочернего элемента с наименьшей высотой

Tags: css

нунжо что бы wrapper имел height первого ребенка, а не самого высокого.

возможно ли это без задания высоты руками?

```css
.wrapper {
display: flex;
border: 1px solid red;
gap: 20px;
}

.second {
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: я думаю так можно сделать только через JS. Прировнять высоту блоков...

Comment: @Мaneken спасибо за ответ) да через js можно без проблем, подождем может и через css можно:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В голову пришел только такой вариант

```js
let wrap = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
let first = document.querySelector(".first");



let a = first.clientHeight + "px";
wrap.style.maxHeight = a;
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  gap: 20px;
  }
  
  .second {
  overflow: auto;
  }

  .first {
    height: 36px;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```